# Customizing the Contextual Action Bar

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

So I'm trying to figure out how to change the color of the contextual action bar menu item text in ABS.

How do you customize the text color and positioning (that is, gravity centered) of the menu items?

I've been struggling with the styles xml for a while trying to change just the text color, but I can't figure that one out.

This is the style I'm trying to achieve. 
Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

[image]

```
 <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Holo.Theme.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.NavigationDropDownStyle</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.NavigationDropDownStyle.Item</item>
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_MyApp</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.MyApp</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.MyApp</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.MyApp</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.MyApp</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_MyApp</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/icon_navigation_accept</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/icon_navigation_accept</item>
    <item name="textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.NavigationDropDownStyle</item>
    <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.NavigationDropDownStyle.Item</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionMode.MyApp.TextStyle</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/MyApp.ActionModeCloseButton</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/ActionMode.MyApp.TextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.ActionModeCloseButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:text">Done</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">invisible</item>
</style>

 <style name="ActionMode.MyApp.TextStyle" parent="Widget">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.MyApp" parent="style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.MyApp</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.TitleTextStyle</item>

    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_MyApp</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.MyApp</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.MyApp.TitleTextStyle</item>

    <item name="divider">?attr/dividerVertical</item>
    <item name="itemPadding">8dip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: you can simply use `mode.setCustomView(view)`

Answer (score 0):

Roman Nurik has made this : https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/R49wVvcDoEW
It's not a contextual action bar, it's just a custom view.

[image: Done | Discard]